# Changing the look of search box

Tags: html, css

I want to change the look of search box. In stackoverlow, as you can see, the search box is exactly rectangular. I want to have a search box like elips( at the borders ), not rectangular.
How can it be done?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Sample Search Boxt</title>
<style>
#search {
 border: 1px solid #CCC; 
 width: 100%; height: 25px; 
-moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px; 
-khtml-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}

input[type="text"] {
 outline: none;
 border: none;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="search" />
</body>
</html>
```

You can run that directly into the notepad++ or whatever tool your using. I didn't include the JavaScript that their using to add that grey click affect, but this has the border radius that you can mess around with.

[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/uBjED/)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
.ClassNameOfYourSearch { 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
}
```

Change the number for the `px` as necessary.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/nynxE/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-radius) on the `input` element.

Or you could use `type="search"`, which a lot of browsers are rounding by default. I'd still recommend adding `border-radius` too as the default of the browser's CSS are vendor specific.